# Не получается отправить данные через fetch POST

Tags: javascript, json

файл js

```js
const sendData = async (url, data) => {
   const response = await fetch(url, {
     method: 'POST',
     body: JSON.stringify(data),
   });
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(
      `Ошибка по адресу ${url}, статус ошибки ${response.status}`
    );
  }

  return await response.json();
};

const infoItem = {
  category: 'Картошка фри',
  subcategory: 'Еда',
  name: 'Вкусная',
  price: 10,
};

sendData('database/dataBase.json', infoItem);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут же файл json, на который не отправляются данные. В консоль попадает ошибка `main.js:7 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Ошибка по адресу database/dataBase.json, статус ошибки 405`

Comment: 405 - Method not allowed. | Вы хотите прямо из js перезаписать файл на сервере?

Comment: На сервере по адресу url должен выполняться код, который примет данные из вашего post-запроса и как-то их обработает. Например, запишет в файл. А сейчас вы обращаетесь по url, который является _данными_ (json-файлом), а не _кодом_.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov хотел протестировать отправку post запроса, чтоб в файл записывать переданные данные(

Comment: Можно использовать Fiddler или Wireshark, чтобы смотреть, что там отправляется в запросе.